# htaccess variable not show anything

Tags: .htaccess

I use below code but `$_GET['id']` not show anything

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.blah\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.blah\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /shop.php?id=$1 [L]

shop.php

echo $_GET['id']
```

Comment: So it looks like you will need to start debugging. What URL do you request in the browser? If the request hits the server, what do you see in the http servers error and access log file? Is that dynamic configuration file considered _at all_ by the http server? What does request logging reveal what is acutally going on in the rewrite engine?

Comment: I reqeust aa.blah.com in browser. @arkascha

Comment: OK, fine. And the answer to the rest of the questions?